# I am trying to select cells from datatable and copy them to clipboard

Tags: datatables

I am able to select cells using selectCells button, but not able to copy selected cells to clipboard. I want a button which copies selected cell to clipboard

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

                   $('#example').DataTable({

                    lengthChange: false,
                     extend: 'collection',
                     dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [ 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf','selectNone','selectCells',{extend:'copy',text: 'Copy name',
                            className: 'btn btn-primary btn-primary-spacing',cells: function ( idx, data, node ) {
                                return table.cells( { selected: true } ).data()
                              }}],

                    select: true,

                });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzA47.png)

Comment: Are you selecting individual cells (e.g. perhaps from one row, or even from different rows and columns)? Or are you selecting specific rows/columns? The solution may be significantly different depending on the answer.

Comment: I want to select from different rows and columns. As an example select from row five and from column name

Comment: Do you mean "_all of row 5, with all of the related column names_"? I think I may have misunderstood...? Perhaps add an explicit example to the question?

Comment: Like in this example if I use copy select cell, I am able to copy on one selected cell at a time, If I want to copy multiple selected cells, I am not sure how to do that-http://live.datatables.net/wutanage/1/

Comment: Thanks - that example helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following contains some small changes to your sample demo in the link you provided:

```
      {
        text: 'Copy Select Cells',
        action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
          var data = table.cells( { selected: true } ).data();

          console.log(data.length);

          var copyString = '';

          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              copyString = copyString + data[i] + '\t';
              console.log(copyString);
          }

          copyString = copyString.trim(); // to remove trailing tab character

          if (copyString !== undefined) {
            var dummy = document.createElement("input");
            document.body.appendChild(dummy);

            dummy.setAttribute("id", "dummy_id");
            document.getElementById("dummy_id").value=copyString;
            dummy.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            document.body.removeChild(dummy);
          }
        }
      }
```

The main changes are:

- it uses `table.cells(...)` instead of `table.cell(...)`.
- it iterates over the selected cells, and builds a single string from the values.
- each value is separated by a tab `\t`.

This assumes you want the results in a single string.

If you want to keep cell data in each row separated from the other rows (for example, by a newline character), then you would have to enhance this code to track the cell row indexes.

Because you are not using the standard "copy/export" feature, you do not get the built-in "copied to clipboard" notification. You would have to add a custom alert for that. I don't think you can use that standard feature for your requirements. That feature is row & column based - which is how it can also copy column headers.

If you are picking and choosing specific cells to export, I don't know of a way to also get the relevant column headings - or how those could be added to the data in the clipboard.